# How to create a variable with letters and numbers for a lexer in racket?

Tags: variables, racket, lexer

I am creating a lexer for a simple language in racket. This language allows variables that contain letters and numbers.

I understand how to create a numeric value:

```
(define-tokens names-and-values (NUMERICVALUE))

(define langlexer
  (lexer-src-pos
    [(repetition 1 +inf.0 numeric) (token-NUMERICVALUE (string->number lexeme))]))
```

And I also understand how to create a variable with only letters:

```
(define-tokens names-and-values (IDENTIFIER))

(define langlexer
  (lexer-src-pos
    [(repetition 1 +inf.0 alphabetic) (token-IDENTIFIER lexeme)]))
```

But I am confused on how to combine the two without the lexer splitting the letters and numbers apart. Is there a way to concatenate the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `racket/lexer`, use `(union numeric alphabetic)` to match digits or letters.

```
(define langlexer
  (lexer-src-pos
    [(repetition 1 +inf.0 (union numeric alphabetic)) 
     (if (string->number lexeme)
         (token-NUMERICVALUE (string->number lexeme))
         (token-IDENTIFIER lexeme))]))
```

Comment: I understand the union, but what does the if statement do? Is there a difference if I omit this?

Comment: The expression `(string->number lexeme)` returns a number, if `lexeme` is a string containing a number. If `lexeme` doesn't contain a number, it returns `#f` which means we have an identifier instead.